# TitleForHeaderInSection throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uitableview

I am trying to create a generic `UITableView` in my iPhone app.
I have a `UITableView` which populates the data using an array via a SELECT query loop.
I add the data into my array and populate the array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.
I get the section header using that array and by using a sort method, I put the section headers in `Array1`.

I would like to have `titleForHeaderInSection:` work by having section 0 be a static header name and sections 1 and later become generic, meaning the header name will come from `Array1`.

I am not sure how can I create that logic since the app always throws `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` with the code below.

My logic: I keep the count of the array in an `int` and see if the value is greater than 0. If it is, I add the section header for and `objectAtIndex:0`, otherwise I use the static one. But when the count gets to 2, for section 2 and `objectAtIndex:1`, it breaks and throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int value = [[self Array1] count];
    if(section == 0)
        return @"Countries";

    if (value > 0) {
        if (section == value){
        return [[self Array1] objectAtIndex:section - 1];
    }
    }   
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    int count = [[self Array1] count];
    return count + 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section      
{
    int value = [[self Array1] count];
    if (section == 0) {
    return [self.Array count];
    }

    if (value > 0) {
        if (section == [[self Array1] count])  {
            NSString *initialLetter = [[self Array1] objectAtIndex:section - 1];

            // get the array of elements that begin with that letter
            NSArray *elementsWithInitialLetter = [self elementsWithInitialLetter:initialLetter];

            // return the count
            return [elementsWithInitialLetter count];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Set environment variable NSZombieEnabled to YES and test your code. Post debug logs here after you do that.

Comment: But moreover, is my logic correct ? I am not sure if that works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're just missing a retain on the iVar backing the Array1 method. declare the array as a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* datastore;
```

Then cache the value you're referring to in the Array1 method in this method (probably in viewDidLoad).

```
self.datastore = [self Array1];
```

Then replace all remaining references to `[self Array1]` with `self.datastore`. Build run and see if it still crashes. (Don't forget to set `self.datastore = nil` in your dealloc!

Comment: @Change message sent to deallocated instance; update your question with stacktrace (gdb > bt is the command) and to which deallocated instance message was sent. Give as much debug info you can, helps you get your answer quickly and upvotes.